# Install Trace compass Eclipse plugin

Tags: trace, eclipse-plugin, lttng

As far as I know Trace Compass is not yet available, but in the project description [here](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/trace-compass) it mentions that its first release will be based on LTTng:

> The initial code contribution would consist of the current contents of the LTTng component of the Linux Tools project (which is the lttng/ sub-directory in the linuxtools repo)

For this reason I installed the LTTng plugin for Eclipse expecting to see Trace Compass features. Unfortunately, there is no option to import BTF (Best Trace Format) files. This is a feature of Trace Compass.

Question: Are there any other plugin I need to install in order to have my pre-released Trace Compass in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone interested in installing a pre-released version of Trace Compass may follow the following instructions of installation:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/LTTng_Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_Environment_Setup

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The original question is a bit old, but in case anybody arrives here from a search engine, there are now proper downloads of Trace Compass, available at https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.tracecompass/downloads.

The BTF plugins are now included in the RCP version, which was indeed not the case before.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download a daily build of TraceCompass (still called TMF or linuxtools trace viewer as of today) as a standalone application from here:

http://secretaire.dorsal.polymtl.ca/~gbastien/TracingRCP/TraceCompass/

Comment: I tried one of the daily builds today and I noticed that the BTF format is not recognised. That is one of the new features included lately. Have you done the build based on:

git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools.git

Answer (score 1):

As of today, even a standalone version of Trace Compass (say for Windows 64 bit) is available at below link:
http://download.eclipse.org/tracecompass/releases/1.1.0/rcp/

This is just a information if somebody is interested in standalone version of Trace Compass.